# Prove $a,b \in G \Rightarrow |ab| = |a^{-1} b^{-1}|$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $|ab| = n$ 
Then we know $(ab)^n = e$ where $e$ is the identity element in the group $G$. Assuming it is not Abelian.

We want to show $|a^{-1}b^{-1}| = |ab| \Rightarrow (a^{-1}b^{-1})^n = e$

I'm not quite sure where to begin.
What's a starting point I can start off with?

Comment: I think it should be $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ instead of $a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Or there might be an assumption about the group being Abelian or something.

Comment: @stressedout It is assumed that $G$ is not Abelian.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that $G$ is not abelian. The statement is true in any case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, observe that $\;|x|=|x^{-1}|\;$ for any $\;x\in G\;$ , and thus

$$b^{-1}a^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}\implies|b^{-1}a^{-1}|=|(ab)^{-1}|=|ab|$$

But also observe that

$$ba=a^{-1}(ab)a\implies |ab|=|ba|\;\text{ since conjugate elements have the same order}$$

Put the above together and prove your quest.

Comment: The last line that you added after your edit was the part that was missing when I was trying to solve it. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:*

- $|ghg^{-1}|=|h|$
- $|h^{-1}|=|h|$

Apply this to $h=ab$ and a suitable $g$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ab . ab \cdots ab = e$$
$$ b . ab \cdots ab = a’$$ multiply from the left by a inverse 
$$b.ab\cdots .a= a’b’$$multiply from the right by b inverse 
$$b.ab\cdots ab.= a’b’a’ $$multiply from the right by a inverse keep going

Comment: Use `$$\underbrace{ab\cdot\dots\cdot ab}_{n\text{ times}.}$$` for $$\underbrace{ab\cdot\dots\cdot ab}_{n\text{ times}.}$$